# Modal doesn't hide after ajax stop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need a "Please wait" modal until ajax request stop. The modal shows until ajax end, but the modal is not hidden after ajax end.
I put `console.log()` in these two states. It works fine, but the modal is not hidden.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">    
        <div class="modal-content">        
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Please Wait...</p>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $("#myModal").modal('show');              
    console.log('start');
}).ajaxStop(function () {
    $("#myModal").modal('hide');
    console.log('finish');
});
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap or another jQuery plugin library?

Comment: i'm using Bootstrap